# Getting floating objects in multicol environments

Tags: floats, multicol

I am using `multicol` with 2 columns, and I would love to have my figures and tables to float, so that I don't have to manually mess around with the positioning anymore. I am aware of `figure*`, but I want my floats to just span one column, not both.

A bit of research points to "won't work", but does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish that without breaking too much of my existing work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, the current implementation of `multicol` doesn't allow "column floats".

There are some projects with the aim, amongst other goals, at removing this restriction.

Comment: I know this is old, but either A) is there a replacement now (a year on), or B) could you mention some of those other projects? Cheers!

Comment: @EricR The *big* project is a new output routine for LaTeX, but it's not for tomorrow. The LaTeX team is hard working on it together with a big revamping.

Comment: Good to know, cheers @egreg.

Comment: @egreg Do you know of any news on this? There still doesn't seem to be a way to combine `multicol` with floats 7 years later.

Comment: @Casimir [Here's the top of the manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1qdd.png).