# Why is my algorithm nowhere to be found in the PDF?

Tags: algorithms, texstudio, windows

I need to typeset a pseudocode algorithm. (I use **TexStudio** on **Windows 7**.)
If I put the code in a single new tex file, I can see the pdf file. But, I cannot see it if I put it inside one of the other tex files. I have many tex files that cannot be shown here. But, the other parts can be displayed well, only the algorithm part disappear.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}  **// add star here** 
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
  \State $a\gets b$
  \State $b\gets r$
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
 \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Compilation works fine (I get no errors), but the algorithm is nowhere to be found in the PDF file. To repeat, I use the following packages:

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
```

If I put the algorithm  part in this way :

```
mark1 
  "the algorithm part"
```

mark2

**UPDATE**

The output :

```
  ----------------------------------
  caption 
  -----------------------------------         
  the algorithm, but , it crosses two columns , is it possible to make it only occupy one column, my article is two column style.
```

I can see the "mark1" and "mark2" in pdf but not the "the algorithm part".

Any idea?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perhaps the algorithm is there, but on a different page. Notice that `algorithm` is a *float* object, so your algorithm might be in a different page than the one you wrote the code in.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us everything that's relevant? Taking your code and putting it into an MWE works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I have checked that no algorithm in pdf file. thanks

Comment: @user3601704 With the updated MWE, do you get the algorithm appearing in the .pdf?

Comment: @user3601704 Try manually compiling the code.

Comment: @user3601704 One more thing, which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: @user3601704 May be, your compiled PDF contains the algorithm, but you are viewing a separate one!

Comment: I use viewPDF. How to do manual compile ? Where to find the pdf that have the algorithm ? thanks

Comment: Try `pdflatex <nameofyourfile>` from the command line (`cd` to the folder you're working in first..) and you should find a pdf of the same name afterwards.

Comment: i used pdflatex from cmd and compiled the tex file, no compile error, in the folder, i opened the pdf file, but still no algorithm in the pdf file.

Comment: @user3601704 And the contents of your .tex file were exactly those of the updated MWE that's now in the question`?

Comment: No, there are also other texts, But, I can see the pdf even though I do not put the "algorithm" part in the file. So, the other parts do not have impacts on the pdf. But, why I cannot see the "algorithm" in pdf ? thanks

Comment: @user3601704 Missing text can be caused by a misplaced `\endinput` or `\end{document}`.

Comment: @user3601704 Let's see whether it's a float problem: try removing the surrounding `algorithm` environment and the caption (but leaving the `algorithmic` one). What do you see in the PDF then?

Comment: @Jubobs, after removing them, I see the "algorithm" part in pdf, but, it cross two columns. Can we reduce it to one column ? Now, I use \begin{algorithm*}, it is correct way ? thanks !

Comment: @user3601704 Good; that's progress. Please edit the code in your question to show us *exactly* with what code you're working at the moment, and what output you get. Otherwise, we won't get anywhere.

Comment: @user3601704 Just to clarify, can you confirm whether you can see the algorithm now? Also, if you document is supposed to be two-column, why are you not using the `twocolumn` class option?

Comment: @Jubobs, i use \begin{multicols}{2}. But, the "algorithm" part cross two columns.

Comment: @user3601704 ... you say you use a `multicols` environment, but it's not in the code of your question! The code in your question must be **complete**, i.e. it must **exactly** reflect the [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) you use on your machine to try and solve this problem. Otherwise, you're not giving us all the information we need. That's why we're not getting anywhere here: you're doling out information instead of telling us everything.

Answer (score 2):

On the basis of the long string of comments to your question, it seems that the code in your question is still not reflecting what you use on your machine. It's important that you give us all the relevant information (but no more than that; see [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) in one go, instead of doling it out. Otherwise, people who want to help you are just fumbling in the dark for what the problem *might* be, and are likely to run out of patience quickly.

Here are my thoughts so far. In your question, you write

> [the algorithm] crosses two columns, is it possible to make it only occupy one column?

However, whether your document is *globally* or only *locally* multicolumn is unclear, because in [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195616/why-is-my-algorithm-nowhere-to-be-found-in-the-pdf?noredirect=1#comment452921_195616), you write

> i use `\begin{multicols}{2}`

but, in your question, you also write

> my article is two column style

As stated in [this article](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) by the author of the `multicol` package, the `multicol` environment is only meant for

> [...] switching between one and multicolumn format on the same page.

Therefore, if your document is entirely two-column, you don't need any `multicol` environment. You just need to pass the `twocolumn` option (along with possibly other options) to the `article` class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
```

I'm going to assume that's what you want, here. In that case, the algorithm gets typeset as expected in one column with the following code. The only problem is that you may want to keep the lines short, to avoid too many line breaks within your algorithm; consider getting rid of the algorithm comments, for instance, as I did in my code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%<--- only to show the page structure

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \While{$r\not=0$}
  \State $a\gets b$
  \State $b\gets r$
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$
 \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

If, on the other hand, you really want your document to be only locally two-column, simply wrapping a `multicols` environment around the `algorithm` environement (which I believe is what you did) won't work, because `algorithm` is a "float", and the `multicol` package doesn't allow "column floats" (as explained, for instance, in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30061/21891) to [Getting floating objects in multicol environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30058/getting-floating-objects-in-multicol-environments)). For alternatives, see [How do I force TeX to completely use the 1st column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53657/how-do-i-force-tex-to-completely-use-the-1st-column)